# Future called in a while loop is not called every time

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future

I am building a Utility which monitors and persists the progress of a file being processed within a larger system. The file is a large "text" file, .csv, .xls, .txt, etc. This could be streaming data from Kafka, Writing it to Avro, or writing it in bulk batches a SQL DB. I'm trying to build a "catchall" utility which logs the number of lines processed and persists the progress to a DB using a RESTful API call.

The processing is always done within an Akka Actor, regardless of the type of processing. I'm trying to do the progress logging asynchronously so as to avoid blocking the progress of the processing. The progressing happens VERY quickly. Most of it happens in a similar batch-style format, though sometimes it does go incrementally one by one, here is a basic representation of what would happen in the processing just for demonstration:

```
//inside my processing actor

  var fileIsProcessing = true
  val allLines = KafkaUtil.getConnect(fileKey)
  val totalLines = KafkaUtil.getSize
  val batchSize = 500
  val dBUtil = new DBUtil(totalLines)

 while (fileIsProcessing) {

    // consumes @ 500 lines at a time to process, returns empty if done consuming
    val batch:List[Pollable] = allLines.poll
    //for batch  identification purposes
    val myMax = batch.map(_.toInt ).max
    println("Starting new batch with max line: " + myMax)

    //processing work happens here
    batch.map(processSync)
    println("Finished processing batch with max line: " + myMax)

    //send a progress update to be persisted to the DB
    val progressCall = Future[Unit] {dBUtil.incrementProgress(batch.size)}
    progressCall.onComplete{
          case Success(s) => // don't care
          case Failure(e) => logger.error("Unable to persist progress from actor ") 
    }

 if (batch.isEmpty) fileIsProcessing = false //this is horribly non-functional.
}
```

And, a simple representation of my DBUtil, the class doing the processing:

```
class DBUtil(totalLines:Int) {

    //store both the number processed and the total to process in db, even if there is currently a percentage

var rate = 0 //lines per second
var totalFinished = 0
var percentageFin:Double = 0
var lastUpdate = DateTime.now()

def incrementProgress(totalProcessed: Int, currentTime:DateTime): Unit = {
  //simulate write the data and calculated progress percentage to db
  rate = totalProcessed/((currentTime.getMillis() - lastUpdate.getMillis())/1000)
  totalFinished += totalProcessed
  percentageFin = (totalFinished.toDouble / totalLines.toDouble) * 100
  println(s"Simulating DB persist of total processed:$totalFinished lines at $percentageFin% from my total lines: $totalLines at rate:$rate" )
}
```

}

Now, what's really weird, is in production, the processing happens so quickly, that the line `Future[Unit] { dBUtil.incrementProgress(batch.size)}` does not reliably get called every single time. The `while` loop will finish, but I will note in my DB that the progress will get hung up on 50% or 80%. The only way it works, is if I bog down the system with `logger` or `println` statements to slow it down.

Why does my Future call not reliably call every time?

Comment: You're showing pseudocode without any synchronization in `DBUtil`. It's easy to imagine you throw an Exception there and never notice.

Comment: I definitely check for errors, there are `Try`s used where appropriate, and the Future's often use a .onComplete{ case Success = > ... case Failure => ...}` The above pseudocode is as stripped as possible for the purpose of abstraction. I'm just curious if there would be a reason that a Future call would get "skipped" for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

Well... so there are few problems with the code that you have,

You are just initiating the futures in your while loop and then your loop goes for next iteration without waiting for the future to finish. Which means that your program may finish before the futures were actually executed by the executor.

Also, your loop is creating more and more "futuristic" calls to `dBUtil.incrementProgress(batch.size)`, you will have multiple threads executing the same function at the same time. This will cause race conditions as you are using mutable state.

```
def processFileWithIncrementalUpdates(
  allLines: ????,
  totalLines: Int,
  batchSize: Int,
  dbUtil: DBUtil
): Future[Unit] = {
  val promise = Promise[Unit]()
  Future {
    val batch: List[Pollable] = allLines.poll
    if (batch.isEmpty) {
      promise.completeWith(Future.successful[Unit]())
    }
    else {
      val myMax = batch.map(_.toInt).max
      println("Starting new batch with max line: " + myMax)

      //processing work happens here
      batch.map(processSync)
      println("Finished processing batch with max line: " + myMax)

      //send a progress update to be persisted to the DB
      val progressCall = Future[Unit] { dBUtil.incrementProgress(batch.size) }

      progressCall.onComplete{
        case Success(s) => // don't care
        case Failure(e) => logger.error("Unable to persist progress from actor ")
      }

      progressCall.onComplete({
        case _ => promise.completeWith(processFileWithIncrementalUpdates(allLines, totalLines, batchSize, dBUtil))
      })
    }
    promise.future
  }
}

val allLines = KafkaUtil.getConnect(fileKey)
val totalLines = KafkaUtil.getSize
val batchSize = 500
val dBUtil = new DBUtil(totalLines)

val processingFuture = processFileWithIncrementalUpdates(allLines, totalLines, batchSize, dBUtil)
```

Comment: >You are just initiating the futures in your while loop and then your loop >goes for next iteration without waiting for the future to finish. Which >means that your program may finish before the futures were actually >executed by the executor.
This is exactly what I want - but would the calls to the Future really get "lost"? I would think all the loops would finish, but then go back and try to "catch up" all the future calls. I really advocated to do the calls in an Actor, for the "fire and forget" and the queue preserving the order, but was turned down due to the overheads.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting of your quotes, didn't edit fast enough.

Comment: The main problem is that you have shared mutable state among different threads calling `incrementProgress` function.

Comment: I know, the code Is placeholder pseudoish code. And the state of all that is really not my question. The main question is regarding the lifecycle of the Futures, can they really get "written off" or ignored if the rest of the code is "finished"?

Comment: Your definition of "life-cycle" of future depends on the life-cycle of the execution-context which they are schedule to. So, when the process which owns the exection-context  exits (finishes), so does the execution-context and so do the futures.

Comment: Got it, that makes a lot more sense, and I think what is was causing the behavior I was witnessing.